# How to delete Keycloak realm via REST API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm not able to delete realm via REST API on Keycloak 8.0.2.

My Keycloak runs on localhost:38080. I followed this documentation https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/8.0/rest-api/index.html#_realms_admin_resource, see "Delete the realm" paragraph. First, I got token for admin user at http://localhost:38080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:38080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=vga_tests' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password'
```

Then I used the token and tried to delete the `example` realm by this call

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'localhost:38080/auth/Example' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN HERE>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw ''
```

(Note: curl commands are exported Postman calls)

I got this 404 response

```
{
    "error": "RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:38080/auth/Example"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect, the address I needed to send the DELETE request to is `localhost:38080/auth/admin/realms/example`

curl command:

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'localhost:38080/auth/admin/realms/example' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN HERE>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Comment: I think this answer also not working.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, using the [CLI interface](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/admin-cli.html) (search for "deleting a realm"),
you can do:

```
$ kcadm.sh delete realms/example
```